# AngularJS model best practice

Tags: angularjs

I have been looking at this document:

[understanding-service-types](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/understanding-service-types/)

Because I am new to AngularJS I am having some problems understanding everything in there. I still don't understand the difference between a **factory** and a **service**, but I will leave that for another day.

The problem I have now, is that I created a **model** as a **factory** and now I think I may have done it wrong.

Here is my model:

```
commonModule.factory('optionsModel', function () {
    var _options = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.siteOptions);
    var _defaults = {
        rotateBackground: false,
        enableMetro: true
    };

    if (_options) {
        _defaults.rotateBackground = _options.rotateBackground;
        _defaults.enableMetro = _options.enableMetro;
    }

    var _save = function (options) {
        console.log(options);

        sessionStorage.siteOptions = angular.toJson(options);
    }

    return {
        options: _defaults,
        save: _save
    };
});
```

As you can see here, what I am doing is setting the defaults and then I check to see if we have anything in our session, if we do I then overwrite our options with the new settings. 
I also have a save function which is used to save the options to the session.

Is this the best way to make this **model** or should I be doing it another way?

Comment: Does it work? Are any errors thrown? What makes you think you may have done it wrong? Surely there are other ways to do what you are doing, but only you can decide which one is "Best" for your use case.

Comment: well, yeah it works. But I read that a service instantiates itself. If that's the case, then I could just put that code into the constructor. Also, I think they may be an angular version of jquery extend which I could use for the options. I am going to have another look and see if I can answer this myself.

Comment: You are using a factory, not a service. You could change it to a service, but one isn't necessarily better than the other. Just different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should think about a model in the way you're doing it.

For your purpose, you can do it in a more "angular" way :

```
commonModule.factory('optionsModel', function () {
   var factory = {
       getOptions: getOptions,
       saveOptions: saveOptions
   }

   // If you need default values, you can assign those here, 
   // but you can also think about adding a dependency into your factory, 
   // that would be bound to your default settings.

   return factory;

   function getOptions(){
       return angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.siteOptions);
   }

   function saveOptions(options){
        sessionStorage.siteOptions = angular.toJson(options)
   }
});
```